# Can I update LINQ-to-SQL records retrieved with db.ExecuteQuery()?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

My query is dynamically retrieved from the app.config. I know that certain columns will be included. I want to update a column in each record returned after processing it. Can I do this using `.SubmitChanges()` or similar? Or will I have to write another `db.ExecuteQuery()` with the update sql?

```
DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
IEnumerable<invoice> invoices = db.ExecuteQuery<invoice>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["query_sql"].ToString());
foreach (invoice i in invoices)
{
    // do something with the invoice
    // flag the invoice as processed
    i.doc_processed = "Y";
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**UPDATE**

Thanks to madd0's answer I reworked the way my application allows dynamic SQL. Instead of entering a query in the app.config, the application looks for a SQL view with a specific name. This way the view can be added and LINQ will automatically generate the type(s)/class(es) and allow tracking/updating using `.SubmiteChanges()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `SubmitChanges` to update your entities, Linq to Sql must be able to track them. The easiest way to do this is to allow Linq to generate your types (alternatively, you can also decorate POCOs with a bunch of attributes.)

If your `invoice` type was not generated so that Linq to Sql can track it, it will be impossible for the `DataContext` to determine which objects have changed and to generate the proper `UPDATE` statements when `SubmitChanges` is called.

If you *are* using tracked entities and [`ObjectTrackingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx) is set to `true`, but will want to use `ExecuteQuery<T>` instead of letting Linq to Sql generate your query, you still have to make sure that your `SELECT` command returns all tracked fields and that your table has a primary key (this is explained in the [documentation of `ExecuteQuery<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx).)

Finally, as I explained in my original answer, you can always  manually execute an `UPDATE` query with `ExecuteCommand`. This is how I do most of my updates because it is much more effective in most cases, especially when updating large a large number of entities, since Linq to SQL will execute individual `UPDATE` commands on the server for each of the updated records when using `SubmitChanges`, whereas if you do it by hand you will most likely be able to write it as a single command.

If you do decide to create your own `UPDATE` statements and execute them with `ExecuteCommand`, please remember to use **parameters** and **not** use concatenation to do so in order to limit SQL injection attacks. Examples of parameterized queries are available in the [documentation for `ExecuteCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executecommand.aspx).

Comment: I want to update them as I process them really (one at a time). How can I do this? My code above doesn't work.

Comment: Is your `invoice` type a tracked entity (i.e. a type generated by Linq2Sql)? If it is, does your query return _all_ of the columns of the entity? Both of these conditions (and a couple more) are required for Linq2Sql to be able to automatically update your table on `SubmitChanges`. Otherwise, you'll have to execute your `UPDATES` with `ExecuteCommand`, which you can do in your loop if you want individual updates, of course.

Comment: No, invoice is a class i created. I expected "No" to be the answer but was finding it very difficult to confirm- can you cite any reference? Regardless, if you'd like to post this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I updated the answer yesterday adding what I was discussing in the comments and a few links that you might find interesting.

Comment: brill- thanks. i will also update my question to make a note of the solution i ended up using

Answer (score 0):

As allways, it depends.

In your case it depends on the // Do something with the invoice.
If you anyway touch a lot of fields of each invoice in that parts, this code is fine. Except for the fact that you can move the submitchanges outside the loop:

```
  foreach (invoice i in invoices)
    {
        // do something with the invoice
        // flag the invoice as processed
        i.doc_processed = "Y";
    }
 db.SubmitChanges();
```

so you will have the benefit of a single transaction (still multiple updates though, so with large amounts of invoices performancewise it will not be the best).

If the // do something is relatively plain and simple, I would code the entire // do something logic inside a query and execute that inside the sql, effectively reducing your code to

```
db.ExecuteQuery<invoice>(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["do_something_update_query_sql"].ToString());
```

This way it will be most performant, but you do not use any of the ORM parts of Linq2sql.

Comment: the `// do something` isn't sql based so i can't move it into the query :) the `db.SubmitChanges();` command isn't working... any idea why?

Comment: no error, but the table isn't updated. running a sql trace i see the select statement but never any update

Comment: if you retrieve entities with native sql, I suspect these entities are not in your database context, they are just objects. Maybe you have to attach them first.

Comment: my context doesn't have a `.attach` or `.savechanges` method :/